# Rails 3 Nested Partials, Collections, Locals (Rails Tutorial 2nd Ed : Chapter 10, Exercise 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections, partials, railstutorial.org

Working through [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial 2nd Ed Chapter 10 Exercise 5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts?version=3.2#sec%3amicropost_exercises), I've run into problem with partials and collections and using a partial within a partial.

Chapter 10, Exercise 5 states:
**"Using partials, eliminate the duplication in the delete links from Listing 10.46 and Listing 10.47."**

Listing 10.46 : app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Listing 10.47 : app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
    <span class="user">
      <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

My approach was to create this file
shared/_item_delete_link.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "delete", item, method:  :delete,
                                 confirm: "You sure?",
                                 title:   item.content %>
```

Then use this partial in the original partials like this:

Listing 10.46 : app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb

```
<li>
    <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
    <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/item_delete_link', collection: @microposts, as: :item %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Listing 10.47 : app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/item_delete_link', collection: @feed_items, as: :item %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

This got all my tests to pass, so I thought it was working until I checked it in the browser:
http://grab.by/daUk

The entire collection is being rendered again for each of the _item_delete_link partials, whereas what I wanted was to pass through the local variable from the original collection used in the parent partial.

I tried using the `locals: { }` and the `object:` options for render, but had no luck.

Anyone know the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, just figured it out:   `<%= render partial: 'shared/item_delete_link', locals: { item: micropost } %>` and   `<%= render partial: 'shared/item_delete_link', locals: { item: feed_item } %>` .... Makes sense, just have to pass the locals through ... I tried this before but did `item: @feed_item` and `item: @micropost`, but i needed to pass the local variable through, not the object. duh

Comment: Please show the exact code using `locals:`. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. You want to pass the locals through to the nested partial, not re-render the collection. To do this, must use the `locals: { symbol: :original-local }` option (written using the new Ruby hash syntax).

So, the answer should be this:

The partial ...
app/views/shared/_item_delete_link.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "delete", item, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?",
        title: item.content %>
```

Listing 10.46 : app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/item_delete_link', locals: { item: micropost } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Listing 10.47 : app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/item_delete_link', locals: { item: feed_item } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

---

**ADDING TO THE PARTIAL:**
It's possible to refactor this a bit and also include the user conditional into the partial. So, you can make the partial into:

app/views/shared/_item_delete_link.html.erb

```
<% if current_user?(item.user) %>
<%= link_to "delete", item, method:  :delete, 
       confirm: "You sure?", title: item.content %>
<% end %>
```

Then the calls to render must pass in user as well. So,
Listing 10.46 : app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "shared/item_delete_link", 
           locals: { item: micropost, user: @user } %>
```

Listing 10.47 : app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "shared/item_delete_link", 
          locals: { item: feed_item, user: @user } %>
```

**ANOTHER QUESTION:**
I am confused about when to pass in the object, versus a local variable.
In this case, I had to pass in the local variables `micropost` and `feed_item`, but the instance variable `@user`.

Anyone know why this is true in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The following slightly less verbose implementation worked for me (in Rails 3.2.14) :

No changes to the partial (listed here for posterity) :

```
<% if current_user?(item.user) %>
<%= link_to "delete", item, method:  :delete, 
       confirm: "You sure?", title: item.content %>
<% end %>
```

Changes to the following -

apps/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb :

```
<%= render 'shared/micropost_delete_link', :item => micropost %>
```

apps/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb :

```
<%= render 'shared/micropost_delete_link', :item => feed_item %>
```

Note:

1. When passing a string as the first argument to render it is assumed to be a partial
2. This method of passing local variables only applies to Rails 3, I believe [Rails 4 may require local variables to be passed via the locals hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)